# How to add node to PATH in Jenkins?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, virtual-machine

I've launched Jenkins to my Virtual machine agent. My virtual machine is Ubuntu 20.04. When I run node -v on VM, I get `v16.20.1`. But when I run this pipeline in Jenkins:

```
pipeline {

    agent {
        label 'ubuntu-server'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Hello World') {
            steps {
                sh '/home/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.1/bin/node -v' //1
                sh 'node -v' //2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first "sh" command returns node version, but the second gives an error message:

```
+ /home/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.1/bin/node -v
v16.20.1
+ node -v
/home/jenkins/jenkins_slave/workspace/forgejo-app@tmp/durable-90f345a5/script.sh: 1: node: not found
```

I thought it was a problem with PATH variable, so I found this solution:

```
pipeline {

    agent {
        label 'ubuntu-server'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Hello World') {
            steps {
                withEnv( ["PATH=/home/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.1/bin/node:$env.PATH"]){
                    sh 'echo $PATH'
                    sh 'node -v'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it's non helping and I still get the same error:

```
+ node -v
/home/jenkins/jenkins_slave/workspace/forgejo-app@tmp/durable-a9e9321a/script.sh: 1: node: not found
```

I've also checked what is inside of durable-a9e9321a/script.sh file and it's empty.

Comment: Does your VM host the Jenkins-Controller or is it connected as an agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed my pipeline like this and it's working now:

```
pipeline {

    agent {
        label 'ubuntu-server'
    }
    environment{
        PATH = "/home/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
    }    
    stages {
        stage('Hello World') {
            steps {
                sh 'node -v'
                sh 'npm -v'
                sh 'pwd'
                sh 'go version'
                cleanWs()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Jenkins executor might not have the authorization to run such command. I can't give you more details since I work mainly on Windows but try using `sudo node -v`.

Answer (score 0):

you can switch user to `jenkins` (su jenkins) and install node from `jenkins` user. will be much cleaner and always works

issue occurs because jenkins run executor under `jenkins` user and you testing everything under another user(your personal one)